# Postal address field does not display in node

Tags: 7, ajax, entities

In drupal 7, I am using a '**postal address**' field, with the widget '**Address autocomplete**' for my node. A full address is obtained and saved every time a new node is created. However, it does not display the address on the node's page.

FYI, in the 'manage display' of the content type, the field is visible with the format on 'default' and the option is 'use widget configuration'. I have already tried the other option of deselecting the 'use widget configuration'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If someone else has worked on this site, perhaps they created a template file for the content type or the node. So go to the theme's template folder and look for node templates. Ex: `node--article.tpl.php` or `node--[nid].tpl.php`.  If they are using a template file, then you need to `print` the Postal Address field here, else it will never show up.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a simple tpl issue. I think it's related to some compatibility with the Location module.